# CSS arrange full sized divs below each other

Tags: css

Consider following illustration:

[image]

DIV ONE occupies entire screen and on scrolling DIV FIVE can be viewed. On butto n click though, DIV TWO/THREE/FOUR slide from left to right to occupy 50% of the screen.

So far my CSS looks like following:

```
.div-one {
  background: url("../../../assets/images/manhattan-min.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;

  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 500px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: block;
}
.div-two {
  position: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  -webkit-animation: left-to-right-div2 0.2s forwards;
  animation: left-to-right-div2 0.2s forwards;
}
.div-three {
  position: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  -webkit-animation: left-to-right-div3 0.2s forwards;
  animation: left-to-right-div3 0.2s forwards;
}
.div-four {
  position: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  -webkit-animation: left-to-right-div3 0.2s forwards;
  animation: left-to-right-div3 0.2s forwards;
}

.div-five{
  position: relative;
  min-height: 250px;
  min-height: 50vh;
  background-color: brown;
  display: block;

}
```

With this styling, DIV ONE, TWO, THREE and FOUR render correctly. However, div FIVE is overlapping on DIV ONE. How can I fix this?

Current result renders like following before button click:

[image]

My HTML (it's React code, sorry):

```
<div>
    <If condition={this.state.showFullSizedImage}>

        {/* Main div with full sized background image */}
        <div className="div-one">

        </div>

        {/* Product details div */}
        <If condition={!this.state.showRegistration && !this.state.showLogin}>
            <div className="div-five">

            </div>
        </If>



        {/* Show half page registration */}
        <If condition={this.state.showRegistration}>
            <div className="div-two">

            </div>
        </If>


        {/* Show half page login */}
        <If condition={this.state.showLogin}>
            <div className="div-three">

            </div>
        </If>

       {/* Show half page Password forget */}
       <If condition={this.state.showPwdForgot}>
          <div className="div-four">

          </div>
    </If>

    </If>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please create a fiddle/codepen for us to work with? Also, add in your full code, HTML + JS. Thanks.

Comment: Need more clarification for this. Not getting what you want to do.

Comment: Well it's because your div's 1,2, 3 and 4 are in fixed position which set the position through a non-flow element. So this will never work at this way. If you give us your code I will take a deeper look into and try to help you!

Comment: I have updated my question with HTML as well. Sorry. it's not pure HTML, I am using React.